# How to cache API response and use it later in react & redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my React based application, there is a rest API call which fetches all the data in one shot which is needed for the whole page. The response has data which can be used in a population of dropdowns as well. But I am not sure how this can be achieved. I am currently making a new request whenever the drop-down value is selected. Please do suggest me how to do implement it efficiently without making multiple unwanted rest calls.

Comment: Hi, Did you implement this. If so please tell me how.?

Comment: Yeah .. I have implemented this..
you have to create a state variable which should hold the json response or the data.
then using willreceiveprops and render, you can use the state variable and implement it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

you can cache in HDD or RAM.

- HDD = e.g. localStorage
- RAM = application state, e.g. redux store.

**For localStorage** you can use my little plugin for this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/localstorage-ttl

**In app state (RAM)** - fire action to fetch data, use redux-thunk, redux-saga or similar to make a call and with reducer save data in the store. Retrieve data from store.

https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk
https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga

Comment: I added +1. And I thing somebody(who putted -1) doesn't undestood where redux and browser storage are located internally ;)))

Answer (score 9):

You could choose a [redux-cached-api-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-cached-api-middleware) (disclaimer: I'm the author of this library), that's especially built for such cases.

Here's an example that might fit your case:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import api from 'redux-cached-api-middleware';
import Dropdown from './Dropdown';
import Error from './Error';

class ExampleApp extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchData();
  }

  render() {
    const { result } = this.props;
    if (!result) return null;
    if (result.fetching) return <div>Loading...</div>;
    if (result.error) return <Error data={result.errorPayload} />;
    if (result.successPayload) return <Dropdown items={result.successPayload} />;
    return <div>No items</div>;
  }
}

ExampleApp.propTypes = {
  fetchData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  result: PropTypes.shape({}),
};

const CACHE_KEY = 'GET/items';

const enhance = connect(
  state => ({
    result: api.selectors.getResult(state, CACHE_KEY),
  }),
  dispatch => ({
    fetchData() {
      return dispatch(
        api.actions.invoke({
          method: 'GET',
          headers: { Accept: 'application/json' },
          endpoint: 'https://my-api.com/items/',
          cache: {
            key: CACHE_KEY,
            strategy: api.cache
              .get(api.constants.SIMPLE_SUCCESS)
              .buildStrategy(),
          },
        })
      );
    },
  })
);

export default enhance(ExampleApp);
```

It will fetch from API only once, and whenever you call `fetchData` it will return data from the cache, even if the call is from another component.

The setup for this library is as follows:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { apiMiddleware } from 'redux-api-middleware';
import api from 'redux-cached-api-middleware';
import reducers from './reducers';

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    ...reducers,
    [api.constants.NAME]: api.reducer,
  }),
  applyMiddleware(thunk, apiMiddleware)
);
```

With this approach after user re-loads the page all redux state will be lost, if you'd like to save that state you could choose a [redux-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist) library to sync the state to `localStorage` and use would probably use different [caching strategy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-cached-api-middleware#caching-strategies) for `redux-cached-api-middleware`.

Comment: Can you have any example sample for this?

Comment: @AkbarBasha yes, I have made a couple [demos][https://github.com/buz-zard/redux-cached-api-middleware#demos]

Comment: thanks also i have call the api in action in that section how can i use your code?

Comment: I have call the api in action here how can i achieve this requirement using your suggestion? can you pls give any guide? with example is so helpful for me.. thanks in advance @Karolis

Comment: @AkbarBasha you could open a help issue at https://github.com/buz-zard/redux-cached-api-middleware/issues with your full code, and I'll try to help there.

Comment: @KarolisŠarapnickis Is there any kind of way to do same feature in Vue and vuex?

Comment: unnecessary https://web.dev/http-cache/ - instead of caching on client side you can just tweak responses of API and browser will cache them for you ... ofc if you have control over web API.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this NPM lib, it has a built in cache. Looks like is what you are looking for.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/reqmate

Check the example

```
  const response = await reqmate
  .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .setCaching(3000) 
  .send();
```

After setting the cache, it will automatically detect if you are sending the same cached request and it will give you what ever is in the cache until it expires.

Answer (score 0):

As I guessed you are using redux for state management. And You want to cache api calls for efficient controll state changes for avoiding rerendering Components, unnecessarry API calls and being friendly for Mobile Users (with avoiding fetchig same data(not changed) multiple time). If so -> then you can use ready solution for it.

**redux-cache.** please visit below link for additional information and investigate caching mechanizm briefly -> when you need cache data and when you need evict cache.

https://github.com/JumboInteractiveLimited/redux-cache

[How do I implement caching in Redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42980613/how-do-i-implement-caching-in-redux/48803819#48803819)

Answer (score 0):

**If** you have control over API you can tweak it so responses will be cached.
https://web.dev/http-cache/

Comment: Does not work for authrorized endpoint