# Best practice for Redux API concurrent actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an action, reducer, and service for some resource.

Let's assume in this case the resource is a cart, from which a user can have multiple of.

I have the following methods, `getCartInformation`, `getCarts`, `getCartCount`.
And I have the following API's, `fetchCartInformation`, `fetchCarts`, `fetchCartCount`.

`getCarts` returns the cart id's which are needed for `getCartInformation` and `getCartCount`

The question is, what would you do to avoid making multiple `fetchCarts` calls to the API whenever you call `getCartInformation` or `getCartCount` as a side-effect

- Would you extend the API library with a `fromCache` flag, so that `fetch***` has that option available.
- Would you set a counter on the API library of "calls while querying the endpoint" and then just re-trigger the callers of the functions?
- Would you add a check on the action to see if `getState` has already the cart, and if not query and re-trigger the function (might have 2 or more concurrent calls at the same time for a slow endpoint)?

Let's now assume that multiple components might trigger the `getCartCount` call, sometimes you want to call the endpoint when the component appears in the page and sometimes they all get called in the initialisation of the app because the components are all being added. In this case this will call the endpoints `getCarts` and `getCartCount` quite a couple of times.

- Is there some kind of "redux-way" to catch that there's multiple calls to one method before it has already resolved?
- Would you set a counter of calls on the `getCarts` action?
- Would you make the action `getCartCount` depend on the `getCarts` promise response, and have a check on the `getCarts` action?

I know it's a bit complex and long question, but if there's more or less detail needed please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

1. I do not understand why you should call `getCarts` whenever you call `getCartInformation`. Common use case is: (1) user see list of cards (by getCards) and (2) user click on one of them and see card info (by getCartInformation with id of selected card). Looks like you do not need to call getCards one more time.
2. It is usual to divide list of cards into pages. So you always have `start`, `offset`, `total` fields as service fields at every `getCards` call, so you do not need `getCartsCount` at all.
3. When I applied any kind of cache, it was reasonable to me to make it transparent for Redux, i.e. Redux action perform API call in usual way, and API layer decides (under the hood) should it send real ajax call or should it return data from cache.

Comment: It's application logic, but don't think about it like get all carts and then let the user decide, imagine that it's something where there are nested API calls, so basically you have 2 resources that consume 1 api as a previous step, and you need that api there, how would u prevent  to trigger 2 calls to that 1 api when the 2 resources are called very close to each other

Comment: For the point 2, Not all APIS work like that, there are times in which that standard is not followed by the Backend and then in the Frontend you need to segregate the calls...

Comment: The point 3 is something that I've seen done in some projects, but I was looking a little more at best practices and what the community actually tends to do... or if it even was a good idea...

Comment: "Transparent cache" is a good idea, I guess. Some people like middleware (look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42980613/how-do-i-implement-caching-in-redux) while I like decorators (look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-cache-decorator)