# How to solve cache issues on react-redux project

Tags: react-redux

We have react project with redux, we have a lot of issues related to cache, the date is not synced, and sometimes getting white pages.
Any suggestions/references on how to solve those issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the dispatch method of redux when you fetch data from API.
Also, you can go through this link to get implemented caching in redux.
Visit [Implementing caching in redux]

[How do I implement caching in Redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42980613/17291858)

Comment: thx, looks good

Comment: You can vote my answer if you find it usefull